# apache xampp gzip

Tags: apache, gzip, xampp

I am trying to get the GZIP module working in XAMPP window vista 64 bit.  I have added the .dll file for gzip into the module directory and added in httpconf. Once I add it say it cannot start apache since it cannot find the ApacheGZIP module in the directory that is mentioned in httpconf file...(which I can see exist in the directory)...

One more thing in the modules directory I found that it has the .so files(i thought it was for unix) so i tried adding the .so gzip and added that to httpconf and tried restarting. Again it complained saying it is not a valid window application...

NEED HELP
THnks
Coool

Answer (score 3):

You can try uncommenting the following in /xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

You should already have mod_deflate.so enabled if you are using XAMPP. XAMPPLite, however, has that disabled.